# Why InitialContext throws naming exception when call getEnvironment()?

Tags: java, jndi, solace

The exception stack trace does not give much information, just

> javax.naming.OperationNoSupportedException

```
public static Connection getConnection(Context ctx, String factoryName) throws JMSException, NamingException {
    Object objfac = null;
    try {
        objfac = ctx.lookup(factoryName);
    } catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
        throw new NamingException("Lookup failed: "+e.toString());
    }
    if (objfac instanceof javax.jms.ConnectionFactory) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // The environment is supposed to use String keys only
        Map<String, Object> env = (Map<String, Object>)ctx.getEnvironment();
        if(env.containsKey(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL)) {
            String username = (String)env.get(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL);
            String password = (String)env.get(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS);
            return ((javax.jms.ConnectionFactory) objfac).createConnection(username, password);                
        }
        else {
            return ((javax.jms.ConnectionFactory) objfac).createConnection();
        }
    }
    throw new NamingException("Expected javax.jms.ConnectionFactory, found "+(objfac != null ? objfac.getClass().getName(): "null"));
}
```

The stacktrace is:

> javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException
>       at com.solacesystems.jndi.SolJNDIInitialContextFactory$SolJNDIInitialContextImpl.getEnvironment(SolJNDIInitialContextFactory.java:230)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.getEnvironment(InitialContext.java:544)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.getEnvironment(InitialContext.java:544)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.Utils.getConnection(Utils.java:155)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.client.Publisher.(Publisher.java:130)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.PublisherSampler.initClient(PublisherSampler.java:135)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.PublisherSampler.sample(PublisherSampler.java:154)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.BaseJMSSampler.sample(BaseJMSSampler.java:80)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Comment: Please provide the full exception, and for the part of the stack trace that includes your code, please show your code and label line numbers referenced in the stack trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JNDI implementation you are using does not support the `getEnvironment` method, which means that any credentials for accessing the JMS server cannot be accessed by that code. Here is my attempt at a fix (it's possible that this will only work in your case if no credentials are needed, I'm not sure):

```
if (objfac instanceof javax.jms.ConnectionFactory) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // The environment is supposed to use String keys only
    Map<String, Object> env = null;
    try {
       env = (Map<String, Object>)ctx.getEnvironment();
    } catch (javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException ex) {}
    if(env != null && env.containsKey(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL)) {
        String username = (String)env.get(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL);
        String password = (String)env.get(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS);
        return ((javax.jms.ConnectionFactory) objfac).createConnection(username, password);                
    }
    else {
        return ((javax.jms.ConnectionFactory) objfac).createConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot. Is it a defect of the JMS server not to implement getEnvironment?

Comment: Technically I think it is a bug in the jmeter code - it should catch this exception.